# Checkbox not getting disabled using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am facing a weird issue. I am not able to access the checkbox to be disabled using jquery. Here is the code snippet:

**HTML**

```
<td class="checkbox1 col5">
    <input type="checkBox" 
           class="checkbox {{contractorInfo.contractorID}}" 
           ng-click=" massUpdateMainCtrl.offboardContractor(contractorInfo,$index)" 
           id="{{$index}}" 
           ng-disabled="massUpdateMainCtrl.disableCheckBoxAlreadyAddedToMassUpdate({{contractorInfo.contractorID}})" 
           ng-checked="massUpdateMainCtrl.disableCheckBoxAlreadyAddedToMassUpdate({{contractorInfo.contractorID}})"> 
    <label for="{{$index}}"></label>
</td>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type=checkbox] {
   display: none;
}

.checkbox1 label {
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    vertical-align: middle!important;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(".checkbox").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Problem here is I am not able to disable the checkbox using jquery.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have jQuery > 1.6, then you must use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

```
$(".checkbox").prop('disabled', true);
```

As per http://api.jquery.com/attr/ : "To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method."

Comment: Tried using .prop but with no luck.

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle with it not working please? I see no reason why it shouldn't, it's the standard way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Try using 'prop' instead `attr`,

```
$(".checkbox").prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Edited my ans, Sorry for mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this attribute

```
ng-disabled="!d"
```

so, using javascript :

```
$(".checkbox").attr('ng-disabled', "!d");
```

Answer (score 0):

For jQuery 1.6+ use

```js
Use the new .prop() function:

$("input.group1").prop("disabled", true);
$("input.group1").prop("disabled", false);
```

And for jQuery 1.5 and below use

```js
$("input.group1").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using jquery and angular to control your interface, so I don't think it's a good idea, some people may not agree with my point of view, but  I recommend that  you use just one of these frameworks, in this case only angular.
Try to use **ng-disabled** to accomplish what you want.

For further understanding visit:
[Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled)

Comment: have used ng-disabled but my view refreshes with new data everytime so the ng-disabled doesnt works that time around.

Comment: Problem is that since I have a label for syntax for the checkboxes and have designed the checkbox diffrently with CSS and the original checkbox styled to display:none,  I am unable to disable the new labelled checkbox using jquery